# Can I block root ssh access from external notwork, but not from the local LAN

Tags: ssh

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I would like to root login from ssh locally, because backuppc needs that.
I would like to block an external access with root login.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to be able to allow other users access from outside the LAN?

Comment: yes one or 2 users only

Comment: OK, my answer should work for you then. Access for non-root users is not affected but root can only log in from the local network.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using a `Match` block in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. First, make sure you have this line:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

That will block root access. You can then allow it for your local network with this:

```
## Permit local root login
Match Address 192.168.1.*,127.0.0.1
      PermitRootLogin yes
```

This assumes that your LAN gives IPs like `192.168.1.N`, if not, change accordingly. Also, I suggest you add this at the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure it does not conflict with other directives. Once you have done so, restart the ssh service (`sudo service ssh restart`) and you will be able to ssh as root from local machines only.

Comment: Thanks. Also can I do the following: AllowUsers @localhost @192.168.5.* user1 user1 .To allow only user1 and user2 to access the network from outside, but any user access from the inside?

Comment: @terdon, it may also be terminated with `Match All` if included mid-file.

Answer (score 1):

Using this simple iptables rule, you can block the hosts not coming from your local network, my network is 192.168.122.0 so my rule will be:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 ! -s 192.168.122.0/24 -j DROP
```

if you want block only a particular user from a source

in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AllowUsers root@192.168.122.*
```

Comment: But that will block _all_ access, not just `root`.

Comment: For blocking specific users you do it in the config file if you want to block all external access do it in the firewall. you can do it in both for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

After dealing a lot with this issues I've found that with IP6 interaces you should proably need to add ::1 as localhost origin, even your "external" ip address if you depending of your /etc/hosts configuration

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

## Permit local root login
Match Address ::1,127.0.0.1,178.56.xx.xx
  PermitRootLogin yes
Match All
```