# SSH Key with user and root with shell script

Tags: bash, sudo, auto-login

Is it possible to ssh login to a server as a user with shell access and then change to root user both with the help of ssh key using a bash script?

Comment: why don't you just let your users login directly as root?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - I need to make the server more secure by disabling direct root login. Login as a user and then change to root.

Comment: Do you need the key for root to be stored on your local machine, or is it ok if it is stored on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could do this:

## One key: ssh directly from localhost to root@remote

1. Generate a new keypair if you haven't already.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t dsa -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa -N ""
   ```
2. Copy the public key into the root account of the remote machine:

   ```
   ssh user@remote sudo -i bash -c "mkdir -p .ssh && cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

   (You will need to enter one or two passwords.)
   ```
3. Test to see if it worked:

   ```
   ssh root@remote.host
   ```

## Two keys: ssh to user@remote using your local key, then ssh to root@remote using the user's key on the remote

1. Log in to the remote machine as the user

   ```
   ssh user@remote.host
   ```
2. Create a key pair on the remote machine (follow step 1 above)
3. Copy the key into root's account:

   ```
   sudo -i bash -c "mkdir -p .ssh && cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```
4. As user on remote, test it:

   ```
   ssh root@localhost

   (No password required)
   ```
5. Log out and attempt both hops from your home machine:

   ```
   ssh user@remote.host ssh root@localhost
   ```
6. If that works, now you can [block root login attempts from external IPs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463913/can-i-block-root-ssh-access-from-external-notwork-but-not-from-the-local-lan#463952).

## Issues

If the tests fail:

1. You may need to check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote host to ensure you have a line with no `#` comment:

   ```
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   ```

   and either:

   ```
   PermitRootLogin without-password
   ```

   or:

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   ```

   If you do need to change any lines, restart the ssh server afterwards:

   ```
   sudo -i service ssh restart
   ```
2. You may need to set a password for root on the remote machine (even if you don't intend to use it!):

   ```
   sudo -i passwd
   ```

   That is not really desirable, but could be helpful for debugging.

   To disable the root password again, run:

   ```
   sudo passwd -l root
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I need to achieve the below.
1. Disable direct root login.
2. Login as a user and then change to root from that user using SSH key.
3. I need to perform the above task automatically. 

That's why I asked about the bash script? 

Do you guys think it's possible?

Comment: If you want to log in as root using an SSH key then I don't think you can disable root login entirely. However you can [disable the root password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20450/disable-root-account-in-ubuntu#20453), making a key the only way to log in.

Comment: You can also allow root login only from the local machine, not from a remote machine. I added that to my answer as point 6.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your ssh config file (/etc/ssh/shd_config probably), write:

```
Match User SomeUserName
        ForceCommand echo "*** Now Becoming Root ***" && sudo -i
```

you would enter the passwords manually, if you are using passwords...
anyhow, restart ssh to have the configuration file reloaded.

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: I want to automate that part. Avoid entering password manually and to login as root via ssh key after login as user via ssh key. Is it possible via a bash script?

Comment: sure,  but it would be a bad idea to write your password in plain text any-place.  im not sure why you want a bash script when you can achieve the same functionality from using the server config file.  http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: No no. I don't want to use password. Just ssh key only for both user login and then change to root after login as user.